# Basic java parameterised constructors benefit

Tags: java

Can anyone help me by describing the benefit of using parameterised constructor
i know constructors is used to initialize objects and parameterised constructor is used to initialize objects by passing particular value.

program 1
    //public class Pc {

```
//    int id;
//    String name;

 //   public void display(int x, String n) {
 //       id = x;
 //       name = n;
//        System.out.println("id:" + id + "and name is:" + name);
//    }

 //   public static void main(String[] args) {
   //     Pc obj1 = new Pc();
   //     obj1.display(12, "arun");
   //     obj1.display(23, "cfggg");
   // }
```

// }

```
program 2

public class Pc {

  //  int id;
  //  String name;

  //  public void Display() {
  //      System.out.println("id is:" + id + " and name is:" + name);
  //  }

   // public Pc(int id, String name) {
    //    this.id = id;
    //    this.name = name;
   // }

   // public static void main(String[] args) {
   //   Pc obj1 = new Pc(12, "arun");
   //     obj1.Display();
   //Pc obj2 = new Pc(23,"aaa");
   //     obj2.Display();
   // }
```

// }

is there is any logic in creating different object and initializing it using parameterised constructor than using methods

Comment: you can learn about that here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: The main benefit is; "parameterised constructor is used to initialize objects by passing particular value."

Comment: in a web application or in any java application give a situation to use parameterised constructor@T.J.Crowder

Comment: @CimyRiya: That clarifies nothing. Are you asking why we have things like `ArrayList(int)` (to set the capacity), `ArrayList(Collection<? extends E>)` (to copy a list), etc., instead of just having `ArrayList()` and then using mutator methods?

Comment: jst give a situation in which parameterised constructor is used.i am not asking for a example @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @CimyRiya: How is "give a situation" not asking for an example? Again: What are you actually asking about? It's unclear from your question, which you've no refused twice to clarify by editing.

Comment: edited @T.J.Crowder

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. When both asking and editing, there was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Please take the time to make your question clear and properly formatted.

Comment: So the answer to my *"Are you asking why..."* question above was: Yes.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it saves you having to call each setter method individually. You also don't want to worry someone using your class about having to set each individual value through setters before the methods can be properly used. Just input all the values you need into the constructor and you're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

In general, is the same.

The only differece is when you have a `final` variable in your class.

You can only assign a value to a final variable when declaring it (typical for class constancts) or in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking why we have things like [`ArrayList(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-int-) (to set the capacity), [`ArrayList(Collection<? extends E>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-) (to copy a list), etc., instead of just having [`ArrayList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList--) and then using mutator methods, there are a couple of reasons:

1. In general, classes should be designed such that their instances cannot be in an invalid state. Some classes require information to set the state of their instances. In that situation, we take the necessary information in the constructor's parameters.
2. Immutable classes are hugely useful, and by their nature, the only way to set their unchanging state is within their constructor. If any of that state needs to be set externally, the way you do that is by providing parameters to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

1. First thing is to reduce the burden of setters.
2. Immutability of a Class.

But watch out, too many parameters in a constructor is ugly way of writing code. You can see [builder pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html) for example.